# How to return error code & message from the custom WIF based SecurityTokenService when user authentication fails?

Tags: .net, wcf, wif, wse, sts-securitytokenservice

I am building my custom Security Token Service inheriting from the Windows Identity Foundation's [SecurityTokenService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/microsoft.identitymodel.securitytokenservice.securitytokenservice.aspx) .

However, I do not find any appropriate method which I can use to inform client application about the authentication failure details when authentication fails.

**In case of WIF based custom STS, how to inform client about authentication failure and the reason (error code/message) of the failure?** There is no method which returns `boolean` True or False.

**I can throw some exception, but is it a recommended way?**

It seems clients always expect some Claims in the object STS returns. But when authentication is failed, how come there will be any Claim? **Or which Claims to return when authentication is failed?**

I went through many WIF related samples available on various forums, but nothing helped me to answer my queries.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the right thing to return some Claims of the user who is not authenticated ! Claims are not meant for this purpose. So returning some claim (which tells about authentication failure) is not the solution.

**About 500 status code:**

When error is reported by the WCF service using Fault Contract/Exception, 500 is the default HTTP status code used. So if you see the 500 status code, it's not an error; it's expected.

Having said this, you can change the status code by writing your custom service behavior and the class which implements `IErrorHandler`.

Refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070621/wcf-typed-faults-and-internal-server-error-code-500). It gave me these inputs.